# How do I remove the "unsupported option 'greedy'" warning in this ANTLR grammar?

Tags: parsing, antlr4, antlr3

Converting ANTLR 3 to ANTLR 4. I have a gabillion warnings just like this. I have found other SO questions about greedy but not this particular one.

```
table_reference: // table_ref in sql_yacc.yy, we use table_ref here for a different rule.
    table_factor ( options { greedy = true; }: join)*
;
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have the answer for C#,

https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-use-antlr-4-on-net-4361915b670f

You might apply the same tip for other languages,

> Use *? instead of * as options {greedy=false} is gone.

**Updated: Official documentation from ANTLR 4 is [here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/wildcard.md).**

Comment: This fix is not target language dependent, but a pure change in the ANTLR grammar syntax.

Comment: Are \*? and ?\* equivalent?

Comment: `?*`? What you do want to achieve by using this? `*?` is the new and the only syntax for non-greedy matching.

Comment: @LexLi I am trying to achieve a migration of an ANTLR 3 grammar/Lexxer to ANTLR 4. The questions I am asking are me just trying to feel my way along.